# how to force redirect to home page if inactive in jquery mvc application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have asp.net mvc application,i want to force automatic logout when user idle for 20 min.
Also if user is moving mouse on the browser i want to retain his session timeout.
For this i had written code as

```
<body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var timoutNow = @Session.Timeout*60000; // Timeout in 2 mins.

        var timeoutTimer;

        // Start timers.
        function StartTimers() {
         //   warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
             setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
            $.get("@Url.Action("ResetSession", "Home")", function () {
              //  debugger
                timoutNow = @Session.Timeout*60000; // Timeout in 2 mins.
              //  debugger

                 setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
            });          
        }

        // Reset timers.
        function ResetTimers() {

            clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
            StartTimers();

        }


        // Logout the user.
        function IdleTimeout() {

                window.location =path + "/Home/Logout" + window.location.search;

        }
</script>
```

Server side :

```
 public void ResetSession()
        {

            Session.Timeout = 1;

        }
```

But the problem is that even if user continuously moving mouse in browser ,it redirect to logout after given time.

Comment: You need to assign setTimeout to timeoutTimer otherwise clearTimeout(timeoutTimer) doesn't really do anything. `timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't defined it any events on the window. Add this to your code:

```html
<body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var timoutNow = @Session.Timeout*60000; // Timeout in 2 mins.

        var timeoutTimer;

        // Start timers.
        function StartTimers() {
         //   warningTimer = setTimeout("IdleWarning()", timoutWarning);
             setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
            $.get("@Url.Action("ResetSession", "Home")", function () {
              //  debugger
                timoutNow = @Session.Timeout*60000; // Timeout in 2 mins.
              //  debugger

                 setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
            });          
        }

        // Reset timers.
        function ResetTimers() {

            clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
            StartTimers();

        }


        // Logout the user.
        function IdleTimeout() {

                window.location =path + "/Home/Logout" + window.location.search;

        }
        /// define keyup and mousemove here:
        $(document).keyup(function(){
             ResetTimers();
        }).mousemove(function(){
            ResetTimers();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: i had added <body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();"> in body tag

Answer (score 0):

Few things to be aware of here:

1. Session timeouts are sliding. Any user interaction with the server will prevent the session from timing out. In other words, you merely need to make a request to the server; it's not necessary to explicitly modify the session timeout with that request.
2. Authentication timeouts are absolute. In your auth config, you can customize the time authentication should be active for. When that amount of time, or the default amount, as passed, the user will de-authenticated, whether they are actively using the site or not.
3. Both sessions and authentication are cookie-based, which is to say there is a client-side component. The server cannot directly void a session or authentication on the user's machine. It can only invalidate those at the server. That means the client will not be affected until they make a new request. Only at that point will their cookie be invalidated, and a new session will be assigned or they will be prompted to re-authenticate.

Given that, if you want to do something like redirect the user to the login page *immediately* when their authentication expires, you would have to set a client-side timer to track this. When that client-side timer expires, you can do a redirect on the client-side via `location.href` to the login page manually, and since the user's authentication would have actually expired by this point, it should be seemless. The tricky part is that you would also need to persist this particular timer across page views, since again, it's absolute. In other words, if a user spent 10 minutes on a page, and their authentication expires after 20 minutes, the next page view's timer needs to start at 10 minutes, not 20 again. You could potentially use localStorage for this. Also, since the timeout for authentication is absolute, there's no way to cancel that from happening just because the user is actively using the site. If you need to do something like that, you'd have to set the auth timeout to something ridiculously large, such that the user's auth would effectively never expire during a single visit to your website. Then, you could use the client-side timer to send an AJAX request to your signout action, if the user is idle.

The AJAX you have for resetting the session timeout should largely be fine, as sending a request via AJAX is enough to reset the session timeout. However, you're currently sending that AJAX *every single time* the mouse moves, which means you're effectively spamming your server. You should throttle this significantly, such that a new AJAX request will be sent on mousemove only if one hasn't been sent in a few minutes. As long as you send at least one request within the period before the session times out, it will effectively never timeout, so it's not necessary to send a request every second or even every minute in most cases.